# TeamCity with custom Build Failure Conditions

Tags: configuration, teamcity, checkstyle

We are using TeamCity also for styleChecking goal.

There is build-configuration, where styleChecking tool generates report (artifact), after that bash script counts errors/warnings and saves it in artifact.

How can I set up custom Build Failure Condition? i.e. we should compare, that current counts of errors/warning in artifact is smaller (or eq) than in previous artifact (last success build). In other case, this build should failed.

Artifact contains one integer value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this cant be achieved.

What you can do is set-up `Failure condition` in `Failure Conditions` section of configuration. Adding new condition `Fail build on specific text in build log` and using new configuration you can do the error calcuation and output fail message.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your build config just needs an [artifact dependency](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Artifact+Dependencies) to the last successful build of itself. You can then compare the artifact of the previous build with the number of current errors/warnings from within your script. In case of increased number of errors you can then fail the build step which will fail your build.

You can achieve this by creating a template from your build config and inside the template configure an artifact dependency to the same build configuration (for some reason TeamCity does not allow setting an artifact dependency to the *same* build configuration directly).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things.

1. You need to publish a service message to teamcity that stores the value of errors/ warnings in a variable. Run your build atleast once so that there is some value for this variable
2. After you have run the run the build at least once, edit the "build failure settings" and add a failure condition on change in metric conditions  based on the variable you setup in step1